# Determine the size of buffer allocated in heap

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

I want to know the size of a buffer allocated using `calloc` in `byte`. By testing the following in my machine:

```
double *buf = (double *) calloc(5, sizeof(double));
printf("%zu \n", sizeof(buf));
```

The result was 8 even when I change to only one element I still get 8. My questions are:

1. Does it mean that I can only multiply 8*5 to get the buffer size in byte? (I thought `sizeof` will return 40).
2. How can make a macro that return the size of buffer in byte (the buffer to be checked could be `char`, `int`, `double`, or `float`)?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Calloc() calls malloc(), malloc.c is over 5,322 lines of code so it is not trivial, but (without research) I believe there is a count value just prior to the start of the buffer. This makes sense to me because free() doesn't know anything about the parameters used by calloc()

Comment: @Marichyasana your comment isn't about  [tag:c], it's about *some* (hypothetical?) implementation. The implementation is free to chose how to store the information needed for `free()` to work. A dedicated size field isn't necessary, in fact, just a pointer to the next block is probably easier to do. Of course, you *could* implement your own replacement `malloc()` that also provides some `sizeOfChunk()` function, but that would be an *extension* to the language. And, btw, pointless, the program allocating a chunk *knows* the size (it passed it to the allocation function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4 , (*emphasis mine*)

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand.** [...]

So, using `sizeof` you cannot get the size of the memory location pointed to by a pointer. You need to keep a track on that yourself.

To elaborate, your case is equivalent to `sizeof (double *)` which basically gives you the size of a pointer (to double) as per your environment.

There is no generic or direct way to get the size of the allocated memory from a memory allocator function. You can however, use a **[sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)** to mark the ending of the allocated buffer and using a loop, you can check the value, but this means

- the allocation of an extra element to hold the sentinel value itself
- the sentinel value has to be excluded from the permissible values in the memory.

Choose according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just tested `printf("%zu \n", sizeof(double *));` and got `8`! As you said `You need to keep a track on that yourself.`, I suppose you mean I should know the size of this buffer is 8*4=40 bytes, is that correct?

Comment: @d33j Sorry? Is the `C11` not visible? That's not a chapter, that's the C standard. :) oh, and it's chapter 6, BTW.

Comment: @Don Right, that's safe and I guess less hassle for you, rather than using sentinel values, inn'it?

Comment: Thank you. I agree it is safe as well,.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(buf)` is the size of the `buf` variable, which is a pointer, not the size of the buffer it points to.

Due to memory alignment requirements (imposed by the hardware), the size of the block allocated with [`calloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) is at least the product of the values you pass to `calloc()` as arguments.
In your case, the size of the buffer is at least `5 * sizeof(double)`.

Afaik there is no way to find the size of a dynamically allocated block of memory but as long as you allocate it, you already know its size; you have to pass it as argument to the memory allocation function (be it [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), [`calloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc), [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) or any other.

Comment: Thank you. Well explained :)